# Getting this error "PermissionError 13:" when trying to save an image to folder. Other files are being saved, what could be the issue?

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, runtime-error

[image: See error here:]

I think this is not really a permission error as some of the image arrays are getting saved into the folder. Every other file was saving until this particular image array.

I checked the folder and there isn't any duplicated file with the same filename as this. So far, code already saved 7,599 files (not sure if this matters) until this img array. Any other ideas as to why I'm getting this error?

Comment: the image name maybe too long, or the disk don't have enough space,  you can **touch file** and rename it to the error file name, check what it happened. check it's permission. you can pass those images without problem by using if name!=""; continue. or you can move those images saved to another directory.

Comment: I assume from the highlight in your image that the problem arises when you try to open the file in 'w+b' mode. First thing to do is print the filename. It may not be what you were expecting. Does the file already exist and you lack permission to overwrite it? Do you have write permission for the directory? As this is Windows, it could be that the file is open in some other application

Comment: I was thinking it's the file name too, but I was able to save other images with the same filename length. Last img file successfully saved: 'Lung_XX-XXXXX_10-08-2009-NA-PET03WholebodyFirstHead Adult-94603_10.000000-Thorax  1.0  B70f-48672_1-065.png'. No it's not opened somewhere because it's currently being written to the directory. As mentioned, I checked if duplicate filename existed and there was none.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to mention that I tried saving to HDD. Tried to save the files locally and I was able to save all image files without this error. Maybe there is a limit for hard disks.